# 40F72633DA770000:error:0A0000BF:SSL routines:tls_setup_handshake:no protocols available:../ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:104:

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-kafka

在使用kafka配置ssl协议时 使用openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1命令验证时报错 不知道如何解决 有没有大神可以指点一下.......................................................................目前Kafka可以正常启动，但是用不了
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgUEj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlRkf.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2qg.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask], if possible post errors/stack trace as text not images/image links. Also you should write your question in english and have a logical title

Comment: How do I solve the problem when I run the openssl s_client - debug-connect localhost: 9093-tls1 command to verify that an error occurs when configuring ssl using kafka Is there a great god can help me with... Currently Kafka can start normally, but it is not used

I want to configure the ssl protocol to take effect in kafka configuration server.properties, but I am running into problems